# List remove specific key and values in flutter or dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Following is my List:

```
List XYZ=[{id: 0, l: 1}, {id: 1, l: 4}]
```

How to remove the 1 position element means to remove completely `{id: 1, l: 4}`?

And after removing element list will show like `xyz=[{id: 0, l: 1}]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use removeLast

`xyz.removeLast()`

or removeAt, passing the index

`xyz.removeAt(1)`